# How to check Multiple Submit Button condition in cake php

Tags: php, html, cakephp-2.0

// View Code

```
echo $form->Create('Survey'); 

echo $form->submit( 'prev.arrow.png', array( 'name' => 'task', 'value' => 'next', 'div' => false ) ); 

echo $form->submit( 'next.arrow.png', array( 'name' => 'task', 'value' => 'prev', 'div' => false ) ); 

echo $form->end();
```

// Controller Code

```
if( isset( $this->params['form']['task'] ) ) {

    if( $this->params['form']['task'] == 'prev' ) {

        $this->Redirect( $prev_page ); 

        exit(); 

    } else if ( $this->params['form']['task'] == 'next' ) {

        $this->Redirect( $next_page ); exit(); 

    }

}
```

// IT Does not work !!!
 And also i have more than 7 submit buttons. and One Final button that handle SAVE logic records in database.
 If there are another logic than that..also suggest ?

Comment: you might be having a "name conflict" within your HTML form... try renaming your submit's names to their values, and check them in that way... also, before you do this, do: `die('<pre>' . print_r($this->params, true) . '</pre>');` and check the outputs from server.

Comment: In CakePhp 2 you should be debugging the 'request' object, use this: `debug($this->request); return;` at the start of your action (in the Controller), this way at least you'll be able to see what the form is sending. Be sure to set debug to 1 or 2 inside `app/Config/core.php`, otherwise debug messages will not be visible

Comment: Also, wondering if you should be using buttons for navigation here, especially since you will not be processing the form-data if the 'next' button is clicked. IMO it would be fine if its function was 'save and go to next page', but if it is only navigating, a regular `<a href=` would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting 2 variables with the same name. (task) If doesn't mind which button you press, you are ALWAYS submitting all the `inputs` contained between the form labels (`<form>` and `</form>`)
Therefor, you are overwritting one of them.

I would recommend you to call two different actions in your controller depending on the clicked button.

For this, instead of creating a form with two buttons, you could create two buttons using the `postLink` action of the Form helper.

Something like:

```
//calling the `prev` action for the current controller
echo $this->Form->postLink("Prev", array('action'=> 'prev'), array( 'class' => 'button'));

//calling the `next` action for the current controller
echo $this->Form->postLink("Next", array('action'=> 'next'), array( 'class' => 'button'));
```

And then in your controller:

```
public function prev(){
   .... //whatever
}

public function next(){
   ... //whatever
}
```

Or, you could also create 2 forms with two different submit actions, one for each button. But it would be the same.